# Warning: Ignoring platform '.DS_Store', not a folder

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

This warning pops up when I bring up the AVD Manager in Eclipse (3.5) on a Mac with OSX 10.6.4. Any ideas of what is causing this?

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem after updating to a new SDK Platform for Android, getting the following message in Eclipse after building my Android project

```
[2010-12-08 13:19:46 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform '.DS_Store', not a folder.
```

I usually install the Android SDK under `/Developer/SDKs/android-sdk-mac_x86/`. There is a folder "platforms" which contains the downloads of your AVD Manager and OSX apparently created the hidden folder ".DS_Store" inside it. So if you navigate there using your Terminal and type `ls -la` you may see the folder and you can delete it using `rm -rf .DS_Store` accordingly. Then everything should work fine again.

Answer (score 1):

[.DS_Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) is a hidden device file on OS X.

I'm not quite sure what is causing this, but it seems that Eclipse is trying to add this to file to SVN. Try adding `.DS_Store` to your SVN ignore pattern to see if this goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Jiri said, but instead I ran the following in the project folder instead of the Android SKD.

```
rm -rf .DS_Store
```